# How to link existing Facebook login to new login from parse

Tags: ios, facebook, swift, parse-platform, ios9

I have created one app with backend as a parse.com
I implemented Facebook integration for login with PFFacebookUtils class.
Now I have logged in with Facebook account. and with same email id i am login with regular login process. But it will create a new row. How to link both user rows?

Comment: How do you want to? Do you want both logins to still work?

Comment: YES...both should work